# About releasing objects created by me

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management

I'm developing an iPhone and iPad application with Xcode 4.2 and latest SDK.

I have created a Tabbed Application without using ARC and I've found this on `AppDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIViewController *viewController1, *viewController2;
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        viewController1 = [[[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
        viewController2 = [[[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.tabBarController = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

May I need to release **viewController1**, and **viewController2**?

Comment: no, because they are sent `autorelease` message.

Comment: Others have mentioned the `autorelease` that you have sent to your view controllers. Another thing worth mentioning is that although `arrayWithObjects` retains its content, it is returned in the autoreleased state itself, so `tabBar`'s retain will be the only one keeping it from destruction. The way your view controllers would get released is as follows: tabBarController -> NSArray of its controllers -> your view controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sending `autorelease` will cause the `release` message be sent later. So there is nothing to worry about, they will be released.

Answer (score 3):

No. They will be sent autorelease, so they won't need to be released by you coding it in.

Answer (score 0):

Sending `autorelease` just add them to the current `NSAutoreleasePool` which is drained at the end of each runLoop. So no need to additionally release them using `release`.

**Tip:** if it's a very large object (or many objects for example created in a loop) you really want to release immediately to dealloc it from memory, call release for **immediate effect** and reducing memory footprint.